# Reference of pronoun it : "to read in English regularly" or "to read for pleasure"

Tags: meaning, difference, expressions, reference

My question is what the first and the second pronoun "it" mean in the 2nd paragraph below. I think that the first it means "to read English regularly" or "to read for pleasure," and the second it also means either one. I'm still debating in my mind. When I think out the question in my own language, both options seem possible. Give me your advice. By the way, I understand the functions of the pronoun "it." Thank you.

> One of the ways to improve your English is to read in English regularly. Spend some time in bookstores, reading a page or two of books that look interesting. You can also borrow books from the library. These days, I'm reading lots of English mystery stories to improve my English skills.
>
> The point is to read for pleasure. Don't use a dictionary, because then *it* becomes studying and you'll grow tired of *it*. If you come across a word ......  (omitted below) .

(from an English exercise book)

Comment: It means "reading" in both cases.

Comment: Don't use a dictionary, because then **that** becomes studying

Answer (score 2):

It refers to "reading".  The reference isn't restricted to any particular type of reading. It means "if you read with a dictionary then *that* reading with a dictionary becomes studying.

This can be confirmed since "reading for pleasure becomes studying" is an oxymoron and "reading regularly becomes a chore" doesn't make sense (if it means that *irregular* reading with a dictionary would not be studying.)

Answer (score -1):

The word "it" refers to the previous sentence:

> The point is to read for pleasure.

But the "reading for pleasure" is the "regular reading" that they recommend, so it doesn't make any difference. "It" refers to the sort of reading that they are talking about.

Comment: "To read in English regularly" and "to read for pleasure" are different in meaning.  Your advice sounds  vague.   I don't agree with your explanation.  Suppose you are an English teacher for English as a Second Language. If your student asks you this  question, I'm afraid your student  will not  satisfy your explanation.  Please give me more satisfactory  advice.

Comment: Maybe someone else will provide an answer more to your satisfaction. Good luck.

Comment: @user152425MH: I see nothing vague in Jack's answer. If you find it unsatisfactory, you should edit the question to explain why it is unsatisfactory. Simply labeling something as "unsatisfactory" is itself vague.

Comment: @Jack and Kevin, Thank you very much for your advice. 
I’ve been studying English by myself, reading books. There is no native-speakers around me. This is the only way that can help.  Every time I read books in English, I come across a lot of unclear points. This problem is one of them, many questions press me.     Pent-up feelings triggered inappropriate language.

Comment: @user152425MH  Don't worry, it's a stressful time for many in the world. Happy new year!

Comment: It's common for "it" to be used somewhat vaguely in English, to mean "the topic currently under discussion", with the reader left to figure out exactly what the writer is saying. But it's clear from the meaning of the sentence that "it" (which becomes studying) refers to reading in general not reading for pleasure, because it's contrasted with reading for pleasure (as James K says).